# MoreLinq Acquire. What does it do?

Tags: c#, morelinq

I was inspecting the Jon Skeet's MoreLinq and I became curious about the acquire extension source code

The [implementation is as follows](https://bitbucket.org/morelinq/morelinq/src/ff35ecd16e764988b794358ee2aeea86ae8444f2/MoreLinq/Acquire.cs?at=v1)

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures that a source sequence of <see cref="IDisposable"/> 
        /// objects are all acquired successfully. If the acquisition of any 
        /// one <see cref="IDisposable"/> fails then those successfully 
        /// acquired till that point are disposed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TSource">Type of elements in <paramref name="source"/> sequence.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">Source sequence of <see cref="IDisposable"/> objects.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns an array of all the acquired <see cref="IDisposable"/>
        /// object and in source order.
        /// </returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This operator executes immediately.
        /// </remarks>

        public static TSource[] Acquire<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
            where TSource : IDisposable
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

            var disposables = new List<TSource>();
            try
            {
                disposables.AddRange(source);
                return disposables.ToArray();
            }
            catch
            {
                foreach (var disposable in disposables)
                    disposable.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

From my understanding it receives a `IEnumerable<IDisposable>` and it creates a `List<IDisposable>`.

**I can't grasp whatever can go wrong here.**

Can anyone explain it to me, and possibly provide an example where this extension can be useful?

Comment: I think that Jon Skeet would be the best suited to answer this question for obvious reasons. As far as examples go, let's just say that I have a sequence/array/list of closed file descriptors and I would like to open them all and do something with them (and I need all of them). If any of the files fails to open, I'd like to close all other descriptors automatically. In that situation, `Acquire` would do exactly that.

Comment: A lazy enumerable might throw an exception half way through the iteration. In that case you should `Dispose` all earlier objects, which this function does.

Comment: All answers are perfect and I'd like to mark all of them as *accepted* but I had to pick only one. Looking at the answers made me feel like "D'oh"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The call to `AddRange` iterates over `source`. If for any reason it encounters an exception, any that had previously been acquired will be disposed. Consider this example:

```
var filenames = new[] { "file1.xml", "file2.xml", "doesnotexist.xml" };
var disposables = filenames.Select(fn => File.OpenRead(fn));
var fileStreams = disposables.Acquire();
```

No exception will be thrown when you're assigning `disposables`, because of lazy evaluation. However, when the call to `AddRange` inside `Aquire` reaches the third element (where it tries to open `"doesnotexist.xml"`), a `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown. When this happens, `Acquire` will safely dispose the previous streams. A simple `ToList` / `ToArray` would leave the first two file streams open.

In essence, `Acquire` is there to  ensure that either *all* the files in `filenames` is safely opened, or none of them are.

Answer (score 7):

Assume you have code which creates and returns disposable objects one by one:

```
public IEnumerable<FileStream> GetFiles()
{
    yield return File.OpenRead("file1");
    yield return File.OpenRead("file2"); // does not exist
    yield return File.OpenRead("file3");
}
```

You need to get all of the disposable objects, but if in the middle of acquisition there is an exception, then the objects which were already yielded will stay in memory and not disposed. So, `Acquire` either acquires all streams and returns them, or, upon failing, it disposes all already acquired streams and rethrows the exception.

```
FileStream[] streams = GetFiles().Acquire();
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that most of the `IEnumerable` collections you get using LINQ are evaluated in lazy way, e.g. you get just the recipe how to generate the list. The code gets actually executed only when you iterate over the collection, which in this case happens in `disposables.AddRange(source)`. If this call fails, then you end up with a partial collection of objects that should be disposed, which happens here:

```
            foreach (var disposable in disposables)
                disposable.Dispose();
```